# Capture screen video while running Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, automation, video-capture

My Requirement: I want to capture screen video of tests while running selenium tests.

I am currently using Monte Media Library. But it capture all the actions that is taking place in screen. I want to capture only the test browsers.

Is there a way to do that?

Please help me.

Comment: Find a screen recording program that can be focused on a particular app... I don't understand how this is a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

Working solution, without using any extra libraries is to implement your own Recording functionality via [TakesScreenshot](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html) interface. This is really helpful for HTML5 games automation. You still can run tests in parallel and record what happen per browser/test.

Simple use:

```
 import static openqa.selenium.OutputType.*;

 File screenshotFile = ((Screenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(file);
 String screenshotBase64 = ((Screenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(base64);
```

The main Thread with the test will remain the same. In [second Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html) you run this snippet every 5 seconds (or as frequent you want and your machine can keep up) and store the frames in a [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html). So for example you need to keep only last 12 items (last minute). This data structure provides first in, first out (FIFO) operations for add, poll, and so on.

Apache Commons collections 4 has a `CircularFifoQueue<>` which is what you can use out of the box.

> CircularFifoQueue is a first-in first-out queue with a fixed size that
>   replaces its oldest element if full.

Simple use:

```
import java.util.Queue;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.queue.CircularFifoQueue;

Queue<Integer> fifo = new CircularFifoQueue<Integer>(12);
fifo.add(1);
fifo.add(2);
fifo.add(3);
System.out.println(fifo);

// Observe the result: 
// [2, 3]
```

Comment: driver.getScreenshotAs is taking long time to capture single screenshot

Comment: I'm using it with C# implementation `Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot) driver).GetScreenshot();` and it works within a second.